# Entity Framework Linq SelectMany with condition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have been trying for a while to find a suitable solution for a linq query I am trying to write.

In my model structure I have my Item class, which holds a list of PaymentRecords.  What I want my query to achieve is:

```
public class PaymentRecord
{
    public int PaymentRecordId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double PaymentAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfPayment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool FinalPayment { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Item Item{ get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public List<PaymentRecord> PaymentRecords {get; set;}

    ...various other properties
}
```

Select all Items, where the PaymentRecord list matches the condition below (which works fine), or where PaymentRecord is null e.g. the Items class has no PaymentRecord.  Is there a way in which to do this?

```
var result = m_context.Item
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.PaymentRecords.Where(p => (p.FinalPayment == true
                                              && p.DateOfPayment >= _revenueStatementRequest.StartDate
                                              && p.DateOfPayment <= _revenueStatementRequest.EndDate)
                                              || p.FinalPayment != true),
                (x, p) => x
            )
            .ToList();
```

Ideally I would like to do something like below, but I have not been able to get anything similar to work:

```
var result = m_context.Item
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.PaymentRecords.Where(p => (p.FinalPayment == true
                                              && p.DateOfPayment >= _revenueStatementRequest.StartDate
                                              && p.DateOfPayment <= _revenueStatementRequest.EndDate)
                                              || p.FinalPayment != true)
                || x.PaymentRecords == null,
                (x, p) => x
            )
            .ToList();
```

After working from the answer given I have this:

```
 m_context.Item.Where(c => (!
                            c.PaymentRecords.Any(q => (q.FinalPayment &&
                                                            q.DateOfPayment >= _revenueStatementRequest.StartDate &&
                                                            q.DateOfPayment <= _revenueStatementRequest.EndDate)
                                                            || q.FinalPayment != true
                                                )
                            )
                    && (c..Type == Booked || c.Type == Reserved)
                    && (c.StartDate < _revenueStatementRequest.StartDate)
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it without the `SelectMany`

```
        List<Item> res = m_context.Items
                      .Where(c => !c.PaymentRecords
                                .Any(q => (q.FinalPayment && 
                                        q.DateOfPayment >=_revenueStatementRequest.StartDate &&
                                        q.DateOfPayment <= _revenueStatementRequest.EndDate)
                                        || !q.FinalPayment)
                            )
    //**EDIT**
    .Where(c => c.StartDate < _revenueStatementRequest.StartDate)
 //this is comment out, so we can better test on the more complex part of the query
  //.Where(c => c.Type == Booked || c.Type == Reserved)   
    .ToList();
```

that way you get a `List<Item>` instead of `List<PaymentRecord>`

Comment: with this method, it does not seem to return any Items where a PaymentRecord is set which matches the mentioned conditions e.g. I have an item with a paymentRecord with FinalPayment true, and it is not showing in the list

Comment: in your example - if `FinalPayment` is true, then the date conditions must also be true. Are the date conditions also true?

Comment: yes.  For some reason the query seems to only return 1 Item, instead of the 3 expected

Comment: hmm im 99% sure the query is right. I belive your data is not that you think it is. Could you post the data you belive should be returned by the query?

Comment: please see my latest edit.  it may possibly be my additional where clauses?

Comment: hmm it's getting very localized. my advice: add the rest of the condition in  seperate `Where`'s, and comment them out (like i did in my edided example) to see which one is cousing you trouble. Try to work on a small amount of data, so its clear what the answer should be.

Comment: well removing all the additional clauses is still giving incorrect data back unfortunately

Comment: maybe we should change `!c.PaymentRecords` to `c.PaymentRecords` I'v might have flipped your condition wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26167/discussion-between-jens-kloster-and-thewads)

Answer (score 1):

> Select all Items, where the PaymentRecord list matches the condition
>   below (which works fine), or where PaymentRecord is null e.g. the
>   Items class has no PaymentRecord.

```
var result = m_context.Item
                      .Where(x => !x.PaymentRecords.Any() ||
                                   x.PaymentRecords.Any(p => (p.FinalPayment == true
                                                        && p.DateOfPayment >= _revenueStatementRequest.StartDate
                                                        && p.DateOfPayment <= _revenueStatementRequest.EndDate)
                                                        || p.FinalPayment != true))
                      .ToList();
```

I don't see any reason for using `SelectMany` here. Simple `Where` condition can do the work.